# Kartik Multidate DatePicker and beforeShowDay with AJAX in Yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I am using `Kartik datepicker` and trying to bold the specific days which are return from `AJAX` response in the form of an `array`. The days are become bold now but it makes too many `AJAX` calls and whenever I want to change the month it takes a bit long time to change. Here is my code

```
<?php
                echo DatePicker::widget([
                         'name' => 'check_multiple_date',
                         'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
                         'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...', 'id' => 'date-picker-multiple', 'toggleActive' => true],
                         'pluginOptions' => [
                             'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
                             'todayHighlight' => false,
                             'multidate' => true,
                             'beforeShowDay' => new JsExpression($JsBeforeDay)
                         ],
                    ]);
?>
```

And below is the `JQuery` for `AJAX` call and bold the some days.

```
<?php
 $JsBeforeDay = <<<EOF
 [enter image description here][1]function(date){
    var dates;
    var duration =30;
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: siteDomain+'/reservation/find-reservations-by-duration?duration='+duration,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {format: 'json'},
            success: function(response) {
                dates = response; 
            },
            error: function(response) {
            }
        });

    var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
    for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i)
        if (year == parseInt(dates[i][0]) && month == parseInt(dates[i][1]) - 1 &&  day == parseInt(dates[i][2]))
        return {classes: 'bold-text'};
    return [false];

 }
 EOF;
 ?>
```

In result the specific days format is changing but it is makeing too many `AJAX` calls as shown in the picture
[Click for the  picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he1vr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can resolve this issue by doing some of tricks here:
1) You can pass dates(ajax response) from current action instead of Ajax request like:

```
render(..., ['datesInAction' => reservation::find....()])
```

and then you can pass $datesInAction direct to $JsBeforeDay.

2) if you need to do this by ajax without passing php variable, you can set flag before ajax request...if success stop ajax request and keep use old dates, but you need here to use localstorage, or global js variable for datas, and flag...
Like this:

```
var dates = localStorage.getItem('dates');
if(!dates){ 
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: siteDomain+'/reservation/find-reservations-by-duration?duration='+duration,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {format: 'json'},
            success: function(response) {
                dates = response;
                localStorage.setItem('dates', dates);
            },
            error: function(response) {
            }
        });
}
```

Note: Kartik DatePicker is build dependence of Bootstrap-date-picker, check this reference.[bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Firstly without `AJAX` It solved my problem by passing a variable from the controller. Secondly I didn't get the second method by applying condition to  `AJAX` can you explain it @Anis?

Comment: Welcome Bilal, in second method we applying condition for ajax, this condition will be named as a flag, this flag will be bool true-dates/false-null-undefined...so that if flag is true thats mean we are request ajax before and got dates, else if its null, or undefined or false...that's mean we have empty dates...now how we can update flag and keep flag value set for all items?...we can do this by save dates or flags in localstorage (temp browser storage) or by define a global js variable out for js expression scope...thats its